# compiling something - /usr/bin/ld cannot find support_glib

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I'm compiling [navit](http://navit.sourceforge.net) on ubuntu
It gets down to this step and fails

```
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -D_GNU_SOURCE -ffast-math   -o osm2navit osm2navit-osm2navit.o  libnavit.la  -L../navit/support/glib -lsupport_glib -L../navit/support/ezxml -lsupport_ezxml -ldl  -L../navit/support/zlib -lsupport_zlib  -lm -rdynamic
 libtool: link: gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -D_GNU_SOURCE -ffast-math -o osm2navit osm2navit-osm2navit.o -rdynamic  ./.libs/libnavit.a -L/home/rory/navit/svn/navit/navit/support/glib -lsupport_glib -L/home/rory/navit/svn/navit/navit/support/ezxml -lsupport_ezxml -ldl -L/home/rory/navit/svn/navit/navit/support/zlib -lsupport_zlib -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsupport_glib
```

Any idea what ubuntu package to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to find the library in the local source tree.

*Downloading...*

Yep.  It's expecting to find the library in `navit/support/glib`.  I'm guessing you missed a build step somewhere that told it to compile that file first.

Answer (score 1):

From the above it looks like the libsupport_glibc library should be provided by the package you are building.  Try doing doing a find and/or rgrep at the top of the source tree to figure out how it is built.  Something like `find /path/to/source/tree -type f -name '*support?glib*'` should indicate what the source file is for the library.  `rgrep 'support?glib' /path/to/source/tree` can help you figure out how it is built.

It appears that there is a package for some version of oms2navit.  The package info is at one of the sites under [https://launchpad.net/] at [https://launchpad.net/~stephane-brunner/+archive/test/+build/1104113].

Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to compile it, [this wiki](http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Download_Navit) includes sources you can add to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
* deb http://navit.latouche.info/ubuntu gutsy main
* deb http://navit.latouche.info/ubuntu hardy main
* deb http://navit.latouche.info/ubuntu intrepid main
* deb http://navit.latouche.info/ubuntu jaunty main
```

Just add the correct line that matches your distro to the sources.list and then just:

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache search navit
apt-get install <whatever it is>
```

That being said, with the following version: [navit-0.1.1.tar.gz](http://voxel.dl.sourceforge.net/project/navit/navit/0.1.1/navit-0.1.1.tar.gz) .  I had no problems with the standard step below in Jaunty.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I want to try to compile it from source, since osm2navit, one of the tools, doesn't work with the latest OpenStreetMap database dump